# Regular submanifolds in practice.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

A subset $S$ of a smooth $m$-manifold $M$ is called regular submanifold of codimension $k$ if for every $p\in S$, there is a coordinate neighborhood $(U, \phi)= (U, x^1, \dots, x^m)$ in the atlas of $M$ such that $x^1 = \dots = x^k =0$ on $U \cap S$.

Then, there are theorems like:

Let $g: M\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$-function. Then a non-empty regular level set $S=g^{-1}(c)$ is a regular submanifold of $M$ of codimension $1$.

**Question**: (From someone ignorant about differential geometry!) What is the practical use of knowing that a certain subset $S\subseteq M$ is a regular submanifold? We know it is a manifold in some natural way, but do we actually understand its structure? It is my understanding that the charts of such a submanifold are constructed using abstract results like the inverse function theorem, so we don't really understand how an atlas of this submanifold looks like. Say, for example, we are given a regular submanifold $S\subseteq M$ which we know is a submanifold by the above theorem. We have a function $S \to N$ where $N$ is some other manifold. We don't have an explicit atlas for $S$, so how do we for example show that the function $S\to N$ is smooth?

Comment: With your definition, $k$ is not the dimension of $S$: it rather is its **codimension**, and its dimension is $m-k$ (indeed, you need the $m-k$ coordinates $x^{k+1},\ldots,x^{m}$ to parametrize $S$)

Comment: @Didier Thanks, edited.

Comment: To the question "what is important about knowing that $S$ is a **sub**manifold of $M$", I'll say that it is the same fact as knowing some vector space $V$ is a linear subspace of some vector space $E$, or some group is some subgroup of another: it gives another context in which you can say things